# Power Bi Embedded: is there a way to set an onFullscreen event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I’m trying to use React to make a Report Component.

I want to use something similar to the on() function to have an event handler for when the report enters fullscreen mode. This way I could pass a Function through props to have it called when the report goes into fullscreen mode.

Something like:

```
report.on('fullscreen', () => {
    props.onFullscreen();
}
```

Does this type of functionality exist?

EDIT: here is link to Microsoft Idea: https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=3ae8a8bd-bf04-eb11-b5d9-501ac524a3e3

Comment: Power BI do not support such event, and probably it doesn't make sense to do so. This is something browser related. It is the one who toggles it. See [fullscreenchange Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_fullscreenchange.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of how you can do this with the PowerBI Javascript API. This would be a good idea request to submit; https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/. That said you do have an option to achieve what you are looking to do: You can add listeners to detect when the PowerBI embedded iframe on the parent page is changed to full screen.

```
function iFrameFullChangeDetectedFunction(e) {
   console.log("screeen changed")
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", iFrameFullChangeDetectedFunction, false);
    document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", iFrameFullChangeDetectedFunction, false);
    document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", iFrameFullChangeDetectedFunction, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! This seems to work well enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Ross_Pauly if you end up submitting this idea as a feature for PowerBI please share the link in your question so we can up vote it to get the functionality out of the box from the PowerBI JavaScript API. I was surprised the Handling Events part of the JavaScript API didn't have a way to detect fullscreen or not. If there is a way to do it its not documented here https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki and I didnt find an any properties that looked like they could be used to see if the report is fullscreen or not.

Comment: @vvv4d I've added the link!